# How to display Binary image in RDLC report in windows form c#

Tags: c#, image, binary

I would like to ask about how to show binary image stored in Sql server database in RDLC report.

Following steps i performed but not find fruitful.

1. Darg image control in rdlc report
2. A image properties box pop up, in use this field i set image field from my dataset
3. Set source type = database
4. MIMEType = image/jpeg

my sample code

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable("DataTable1");
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[7] {
            new DataColumn("Pno", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("Rank", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("Path", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("Input", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("SpecialRemarks", typeof(string)), new DataColumn("Remarksabc", typeof(string)) });
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in selectedRow)
            {
               
                dt.Rows.Add(row.Cells["Pno"].Value, row.Cells["Name"].Value, row.Cells["Rank"].Value, row.Cells["Path"].Value, row.Cells["Input"].Value, row.Cells["SpecialRemarks"].Value, row.Cells["Remarksabc"].Value);
            }
          
            DataSet1 dsCustomers = new DataSet1();
            dsCustomers.Merge(dt);
            ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dsCustomers.Tables[1]);
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

But image is not displaying

Please suggest with code

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your dataset contains two datatables?

Comment: Yes 1 have 2 datatables but i use table with index 1

Comment: So all other data show correctly except Binary Image?

Comment: yes all other data shows perfectly except binary image

Comment: whick columns contains image because I see all of columns are strings

Comment: i made  new DataColumn("Path", typeof(string]))
 
row.Cells["Path"].Value 

contain image

Comment: Oh you made mistake. I gave you a link that will hep you and then let me know if it solves your problem or not => https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-Binary-Image-from-database-in-RDLC-Report-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Sir i following a link which you post . 

but still my report doesnot show any of the coulmn 
here is my code
    reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                DataSet dsEmployees = GetData("SELECT * FROM Records");
                ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", dsEmployees.Tables[0]);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

Comment: So I think you miss some step.Check once again because the post in link is best solution to your problem

Comment: it prompt me an error occurred during local report processing

The group Path Expression used in grouping "Path " returned  a data type that is not valid

Comment: Its because of RDLC report want binary data but you provide an String to Column `Path` so try to change data type of your `Path` column like => `new DataColumn("Path", typeof(byte[]))`

Comment: IF it doenn't help then dont create your own datatable programatically just followe link's steps

Comment: sir, while trying to follow your link, when i make a break point on the following line 
it display records which i want to display on report but report is empty

  ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet2", dsEmployees.Tables[0]);
  reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
                reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

Comment: Are you sure the datatable that you bind to report contains data?

Comment: yes i 100 sure because i see data in debug mode

Comment: In your post, you'd bind `dsCustomers.Tables[1]` and in above commented code there is `dsEmployees.Tables[0]` so thats why I asked you that bind proper dataset

Comment: Sir im using dsEmployees.Tables[0] now, but still no data in report viewer

Comment: did you follow that step no. 9 and 10 in link because that's important

Comment: sir im working on windows form application, so how i use script manager